# How to add an incrementing integer in every execution of a select query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-2008

I have a `Select` query to get the date with format (`ddmmyy`) and I am trying to concatenate (a suppose to be incremental) integer/number right after 'yy'.

For example I want to get this:

```
"21011701"
```

where dd=21;mm=01;yy=17;integer=01.

I will be using this query in a Crystal Report and that every time that Crystal Report is generated, that integer must increment just like a **Batch Number**.

Thanks for your help in advance.

```
Declare @bn nvarchar(max) 
    SET @bn = '01'  

SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 3), '/', '') + @bn BatchDate FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Is this *incemental integer number* starting with `01` for each date? Has each report it's own incremental set? When do you need it (immediately or later)? Where do you need it (print out on the report)? Is there parallel action (multi user calls for the same report)? I think the easiest was a table where you insert a new row for each batch and then use something like `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTION BY ReportID,Date ORDER BY RowID)` to get you running number...

Comment: The tricky part that I saw with this report was to increment 01(yes it must start from 01)  once the report is generated by two of our SAP users. So if user 1 generated this report now that must be 01. And if user 2 generates another report that is 02 and so on. The interval for this report to be generated is twice a month. What i am looking for if there is any programming trick to increment this integer wihout inserting values into the database. What i was thinking is to store the current integer value somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT (REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 3), '/', '') +
        RIGHT('00' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) as VARCHAR(255)), 2)
       ) as BatchDate
FROM TABLE;
```

Comment: no not like that. This portion of query will be at report header so it will be displayed once.